# Kivy: ID error on dinamic TabbedPanel

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to create TabbedPanel in Kivy dynamically from a stringarray:

```
tg_folders = [['0','Folder1'],['1','Folder2']]
tgflen=len(tg_folders)
    for i in range(0,tgflen):
        fl_id = 'fl-'+tg_folders[i][0]
        menu_screen.ids.tg_folder_list.add_widget(TabbedPanelItem(height=0, 
                                                    id = fl_id,
                                                    text = tg_folders[i][1] ))
```

It's OK, the tg_folder_list is my TabbedPanel's id.

Then I try to add a new element to the TabbedPanelItem:

```
menu_screen.ids[fl_id].add_widget(Label(height=1, 
                                                text = tg_folders[i][1]
                                                ))
```

On run Python say:

```
KeyError: 'fl-0'
```

When I try `print (menu_screen.ids)` I can't find this id.

What's wrong?

Thanks, gall

Answer (score 0):

ids can only be set in kv. YOu can instead keep track of the object references another way, e.g. keeping them in a list.